# JTable and its Relationship with the Data Source

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jpanel

I'm building a program that gathers a couple lists of files that match a particular set of criteria and manipulates them as it appropriate depending on the source, type of file, etc... My hope is that it will find the files and display them in a list that is easy to read. The user will select which files are going to be processed from the list, then hit a button that "starts the commotion," if you will.

Right now, I've made a class called DrawingFile that looks like:

```
class DrawingFile {

private static String fileName, fileType;
private static boolean actionable;
private static Path filePath;

public DrawingFile (Path path){
    setFilePath(path);
    setFileName(stripExtension(path));
    setFileType(getExtension(path));
    setActionable(true);
}
...(methods omitted to save time)...
```

My plan, initially was to create a JTable that populates based on a List of DrawingFiles with each of the fields in the objects being a column in the table, except the Path, which would not be displayed on the table. From there, the user would click a checkbox which would determine whether or not a file is going to be manipulated.

My issues stem first and foremost from my being relatively new to programming. This is the first program I've written that people are going to use, that also has any sort of UI.

As such my questions are:

1. Does my plan above make any sense at all?
2. Would it make more sense to leave the table out of it and create a series of JPanels inside a container? (this seems like it wouldn't be best practice)
3. If I do go with the table, should I scrap the DrawingFile class and store the data in the TableModel?
   3a. If so, is there a way I can hide the Path in the table?
4. How do I go about changing the `actionable` boolean when it is (un)checked on the table?
5. On a scale of 1-10, how badly am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If I understand correctly, you have a list of DrawingFile objects, and want to display this list as a JTable, where each row represents an object of the list. Yes, that makes perfect sense.
2. No. A table is perfect for that.
3. No. You should create a custom DrawingFileTableModel class, extending AsbtractTableModel, and using the list of objects as the source to implement the method. Google for "Java tutorial JTable", and you'll find an example in [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).
4. By making sure that `isCellEditable()` returns true for that column and row, and by implementing the `setValueAt()` and `getColumnClass()` methods correctly. The javadoc and the tutorial are your friends here. `setValueAt()`, when called with the index of the boolean column, should set its new value in the DrawingFile stored at the given row index in the backing list. `getColumnClass()`, when called with the index of the boolean column, should return `Boolean.class`.

Comment: Glad to see I'm on the right path. I meant to link that tutorial but must have forgotten while I was typing. If you don't mind, is it okay if I type up what I think the methods you mentioned should look like and have you look over them?

Comment: You can do that. But the simplest way would just to test that it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed. Works like a dream. Thanks for your help.